# C++ send location inside of quotes

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, quotes

Im  trying to execute task scheduler command from c++ but having problems with quotes.

```
schtasks /create /sc onlogon /tn Executable /rl highest /tr "\"C:\Program Files\Executable\Executable.exe"\"
```

How to send those bat command via WinExec?

I try so far this

```
WinExec("schtasks /create /sc onlogon /tn Executable /rl highest /tr \"""C:\\Program Files\\Executable\\Executable.exe\"""", 1);
```

but thats dont work.

Comment: raw string `R"(text)"` (C++11) and `std::quoted` (C++14) may help.

Comment: @Jarod42 wow its work like a charm -> please post like answer that i can vote up -> WinExec(R"(schtasks /create /sc onlogon /tn Executable /rl highest /tr "\"C:\Program Files\Executable\Executable.exe"\")", 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use raw string to avoid to manually escape character, something like:

```
WinExec(R"(schtasks /create /sc onlogon /tn Executable /rl highest /tr "\"C:\Program Files\Executable\Executable.exe"\")", 1);
```

Comment: Promoting [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) vs fiddly escaped character literals, should be the canonical answer for such questions! +1

Comment: +1 to @πάντα ῥεῖ for providing a link.  There are some corner cases that are worth exploring in case your string contains the starting default starting sequence for raw string literals.